# PyCharm fails to debug Qt5 (PySide2) code - Error 'Shiboken.ObjectType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, exception, pycharm, pyside2, python-3.8

I have some experience with Python console applications and now trying to start with Qt for Python (Qt 5.12, PySide2). Actually I'm trying some basic tutorials to understand how it should work.

So, I created very simple **view.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("ClickOnMe")
    }

    Connections {
        target: button
        onClicked: con.say_hello()
    }
}
```

and have following python code to work with it:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

class Bridge(QObject):
    @Slot()
    def say_hello(context):
        print("Button clicked, Hello!", context)

app = QGuiApplication([])
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
bridge = Bridge()

context = engine.rootContext()
context.setContextProperty("con", bridge)
engine.load("view.qml")

engine.rootObjects()
exit(app.exec_())
```

It works fine when I simly run it - i.e. I see an application window with a button. I may click a button and see message printed in console.
But when I try to debug it - it stops immediately on line `class Bridge(QObject):` with following exception:
`<class 'tuple'>: (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError("'Shiboken.ObjectType' object is not iterable"), <traceback object at 0x7fe195b23680>)`

I tryied the same in Qt Creator - works fine, not problems with Run and Debug (the minor issue - messages in Qt Creator console appear only after application termination). But I like PyCharm more so would like to understand how I may fix this problem and continue to use PyCharm with Qt.
If it's important - I'm running ArchLinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago Arch Linux updated its version of Python to 3.8 but PySide2 does not yet have a compatible version causing the error you are pointing out. As they point out in this report [PYSIDE-1140](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1140):

> I'm keeping this open, but it will probably be solved for 5.14, since
>   then Python 3.8 will be introduced as a new compatible Python version.

So you have 2 options:

- Wait for a release of PySide2 that is compatible with Python3.8.
- Or install [Python3.7](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python37/) or an [old version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python#Old_versions) from aur (using yay) and then install PySide2 using pip.

Comment: Wow!... I just occasionally updated a couple of days ago :) 
Thanks a lot for fast answer. I'll rollback to 3.7.
I tried to find this error in google but somehow failed to find this bug report... :(

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a bug in Qt for Python using Python 3.8, however it is already been solved [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1140).

Just update your qt:

```
pip install PyQt5
```