# Installing PySide2 for Python 3.8, Windows

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, python-3.8

I would like to install `PySide2` on my Windows 10, Python version 3.8, despite the wheels not being released for it yet.

Naturally, I have first tried the `pip install --python-version 3.7` command to see if simply getting everything, but for the previous Python version, would be fine. It didn't work.

So instead I installed `QT` on my machine as well as every required dependency and tool to build it manually. I have progressed quite far and managed to successfully build `shiboken2`, but failed to build `PySide2` itself.

The errors I keep getting are about missing DLL-s when trying to import `shiboken2`. Unfortunately, the output is rather unhelpful as it doesn't actually tell me which ones are missing, and I couldn't figure that out on my own.

The error from the manual building is as follows (`nmake` command in `C:\PySide2\pyside-setup\pyside3_build\py3.8-qt5.12.6-32bit-release\pyside2` directory):

```
Scanning dependencies of target QtCore_pyi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PySide2/pyside-setup/sources/pyside2/PySide2/QtCore/../support/generate_pyi.py", line 294, in <module>
    generate_all_pyi(outpath, options=options)
  File "C:/PySide2/pyside-setup/sources/pyside2/PySide2/QtCore/../support/generate_pyi.py", line 251, in generate_all_pyi
    import PySide2
  File "C:\PySide2\pyside-setup\pyside3_build\py3.8-qt5.12.6-32bit-release\pyside2\PySide2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\PySide2\pyside-setup\pyside3_build\py3.8-qt5.12.6-32bit-release\pyside2\PySide2\__init__.py", line 21, in _setupQtDirectories
    import shiboken2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shiboken2: The specified module could not be found.
```

I would normally wait patiently until the wheels are released, but I can't find any information on the progress for Windows, and I know the library is available for Python3.8 on other platforms.

Do you recommend any steps to find out what's wrong with my build (I would normally use `pip install` for `PySide2` so this is all new to me), or know how to solve the problem directly? I know `shiboken2.cp38-win32.pyd` is there and I've also included it in my `PATH` env var just in case, same for `shiboken2.cp38-win32.dll` - but these don't seem to be the missing files.

Note: Should this be a Super User question (?)

Comment: Even PySide2 is not supported in Python3.8, just in release 5.14 it will be, so it is recommended that you use a minor Python version

Comment: @eyllanesc That's good news, thanks! Can you tell me where should I normally look for info like this, including when is the release coming? I know there are multiple trackers and a blog. Unfortunately, I have to stick to 3.8, but I'd be happy to wait longer.

Comment: see https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-1154. Today Qt 5.14 was launched, so I presume that in the next few weeks there will already be a PySide2 5.14 release. I recommend using python3.7 for these weeks and when the new release comes out you will only have to carry some minimal features (the changes introduced in python3.8 are minimal)

Comment: For example, if you can manually compile pyside2 with python3.8 then you will still have a severe bug when you want to inherit from a QObject (most Qt classes are QObjects), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58904586/6622587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows platform simple `pip install PySide2` is not enough, you should make post-install steps. As part of PySide2 installation you got `pywin32_postinstall.py` script (Not sure about Win10, but on Windows 7 the path is `C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\`)

You should run `pywin32_postinstall.py -install` to register DLLs.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that! Unfortunately, I can not verify it works with Windows 10 (64 bit), because I have already installed `PySide2` via `pip` by now - but perhaps I will get a chance to test that with next Python release :)

Comment: @StarterKit I did this but still getting error as "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." foo python 3.7 32bit and installed via pip

Comment: @rahul I haven't faced such an error by myself. But from google I found 2 possible options: 1) package version mismatch between PySide and Shiboken2 (you may run `pip freeze` to check version; 2) duplicated DLL in different locations - here I'm not sure which DLL you need to check (unfortunately I can't give you DLL name)

Comment: @StarterKit, Thanks for the information. I installed 64 bit version and is working on that fine now. So I switch based on the requirement.

Comment: @rahul, I'm glad to hear that your problem is solved :)

Comment: @StarterKit, the problem is not solved, i still can't use in 3.7 32 bit, so i installed 3.7 64 bit to work with pyside2

Comment: Hi, @rahul, from you message it appears that you have 64-bit but installed some 32-bit packages. I.e. I strongly suspect that some 32-bit libraries are missing on your system but you have 64-bit version with the same name - package tries to use it and fails.
It is hard to debug this situation remotely. As a straight forward way I would recommend uninstall everything related and re-install 32-bit packages from scratch.